# Best strategy to index document with Solr

Tags: solr, indexing, document, batch-processing

Im using Solr Version 4 (api spring data solr to index,get...documents) and i have to decide which strategy im going to apply for index my documents.

I hesitate between 2 strategies:

1. Launch a batch periodically to index all documents
2. Only Index the document when this one has changed

Which strategy is the best ? maybe a mix??or another..
I have some ideas about cons and dis of each but i don't have a big experience with solr.

Comment: Not necessarily an answer, but rather to share my experience: Two scenarios both have their use cases in practice, although 1) maybe be less frequent than 2), but it happens from time to time, to re-index everything required by schema/config changes.

Comment: You are right, i sometimes have to reindex all documents when the schema/config changes. However in my case its not important if my data are not up to date (15 minutes is correct delay).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how long indexing all your documents takes and how soon you want your index to be updated.

We have several Solr cores - some have less than 100K very small docs and a full import via data import handler (with optimize=true) runs under 1 minute. We can tolerate delays of up to 15 minutes for them, so we run a full import for this core every 15 min.

Then there are cores at the other extreme with several million docs, each of fairly large size, and full indexing will take several hours to complete. For such cores, we have a changelog table in MySQL which only records the docs that changed and we do an incremental indexing only for those docs every few min.

Finally, there are cores that are in the middle, having about 500K docs of decent size, but on these we need atomic updates every 5 to 10 min for certain fields and full document update for certain docs every few min as well. We run delta imports for these. Full index itself takes about 1.5 to 2 hours to run, which we do nightly.

So the answer to your question really depends on what your requirements are.

Comment: I still don't know how long does it take to index all the documents, the documents are not so big (about 10 simple fields), there are at maximum 10k documents to index, i can tolerate too delays of up to 15 minutes. In your case if you can index 100k documents under 1 minutes, i should not be worry about my 10k documents. I don't use xml data import handler to index the documents, i index the documents with spring data solr (using Solrj) using update command. If i decide to import all documents every 15 minutes, maybe should i  use data import handler format for indexing(better performance)?

Comment: Data import handler is easy to set up, but I won't say it has better performance. You should first try with whatever indexer you have now and see how long indexing all your docs takes. You should not try to optimize before knowing that first.